# Clear Checkbox when Radio Button selection is Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I am using a form builder with field IDs in Wordpress. I need to uncheck a specific checkbox if a specific radio button selection is changed. The radio button's field ID is 180. The checkbox's field ID is 640. Here's what I tried first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('input[name="item_meta[180]"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="item_meta[640]"]').val('');
  })
})
</script>
```

Note that this script was originally written to change the value of a dropdown, not a menu. The only change I made to the code was changing "select" to "input" on line 3.

I've also tried changing

```
.val('');
```

to

```
.attr('checked', false);
```

and also to

```
.removeAttr('checked');
```

None of these work. The checkbox remains checked when the radio button is changed. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Here are the two relevant form fields in HTML:

```
<div id="frm_field_180_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container">
    <label  class="frm_primary_label">Pricing Categories
        <span class="frm_required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_description">Select your meta-category then locate your entry fee in the subsequent dropdown.</div>
    <div class="frm_radio"><input type="radio" name="item_meta[180]" id="field_180-0" value="Independent Film &amp; Videos"   class="required" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'180')"/><label for="field_180-0">Independent Film & Videos</label></div>
    <div class="frm_radio"><input type="radio" name="item_meta[180]" id="field_180-1" value="Film / Video for TV &amp; Cable Production"   class="required" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'180')"/><label for="field_180-1">Film / Video for TV & Cable Production</label></div>
    <div class="frm_radio"><input type="radio" name="item_meta[180]" id="field_180-2" value="TV Ads, PSAs, Screenplays, New Media, Websites, etc."   class="required" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'180')"/><label for="field_180-2">TV Ads, PSAs, Screenplays, New Media, Websites, etc.</label></div>
    <div class="frm_radio"><input type="radio" name="item_meta[180]" id="field_180-3" value="Student Entry of Any Category (with 2 Additional Categories Free) - $45"   class="required" onclick="frmCheckDependent(this.value,'180')"/><label for="field_180-3">Student Entry of Any Category (with 2 Additional Categories Free) - $45</label></div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="frm_field_640_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_top_container frm_last_third">
    <label class="frm_primary_label">Apply Early-Bird Discount
        <span class="frm_required"></span>
    </label>
    <div class="frm_opt_container"><div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_640-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[640][]" id="field_640-0" value="5"  /><label for="field_640-0">1-3 Categories: $5</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try putting an alert or console.log(...) in your change handler function.  Can you verify if the handler is even being fired?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice. How would I do that?

Comment: add a line with alert('test'); before the line that you attempt to unset the checkbox.  Also, if you post the html for the radio buttons and checkbox it would help diagnose.

Comment: I've added the HTML for the radio and checkbox into the main post. Thanks! Will try the alert now.

Comment: OK. I added the alert test and it works. Whenever I change the radio button I get the alert. But it still doesn't clear the checkbox. Thanks for explaining that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach appears to work:

```
$('input[name="item_meta\\[180\\]"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="item_meta\\[640\\]\\[\\]"]').prop('checked',false);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JP3Wk/1/).

Note that I removed the `onclick` (since they weren't defined, their absence generated errors, and if you're  using jQuery *why* are you even using in-line event-handlers?). Also, the escaping of the square-brackets (using the `\\` characters).

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Well, thank you kindly! And you are, of course, absolutely welcome; I'm just glad to have been of help. =)

Comment: Per my answer below, the ` \\ ` are not necessary . . . the final `[]` was just missing from the `name` filter in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a mismatch for the name of the checkbox, between your HTML and your JQuery . . .

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[640][]" id="field_640-0" value="5"  />
```

Here, the name attribute is `item_meta[640][]`.

**JS**

```
$('input[name="item_meta[640]"]').val('');
```

Here, the name attribute is `item_meta[640]`.

Because of that, the selector is not matching the checkbox.  If you update you JQuery selector to `$('input[name="item_meta[640][]"]')`, it should work fine.

As noted by Dave Thomas, you are better going with `.prop('checked', false);` to uncheck the box.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks to both of you.